# SystemC HLS Synthesis Error

Tags: c++, fpga, synthesis, systemc

@E [SYNCHK-77] The top function 'method_coupling' (src/method_coupling.cpp:82) has no outputs. Possible cause(s) are: (1) Output parameters are passed by value; (2) intended outputs (parameters or global variables) are never written; (3) there are infinite loops.

I am receiving the above error when I try to synthesize a SystemC block using vivado HLS. Unfortunately, I cannot find any documentation on this error and I am hoping someone can describe what is going on.

My module is the following:

```
#include "systemc.h"

#define NUM_REGIONS 10

SC_MODULE(method_coupling){
sc_in<bool> en;
sc_in<bool> clock;
sc_in<bool> reset;
sc_in<double> a;
sc_in<double> in_0;
sc_in<double> in_1;
sc_out<double> out[NUM_REGIONS];
sc_out<bool> done;
sc_in<bool> valid_data0;
sc_in<bool> valid_data1;

double input_0[NUM_REGIONS][NUM_REGIONS];
double input_1[NUM_REGIONS][NUM_REGIONS];

sc_fifo<double> fifo_input_0;
sc_fifo<double> fifo_input_1;
float sum;

int flag;

void init_0(){
    while(true){
        wait();
        if(valid_data0.read() == 1) fifo_input_0.write(in_0.read());

    }
}

void init_1(){
    while(true){
        wait();
        if(valid_data1.read() == 1) fifo_input_1.write(in_1.read());

    }
}

void do_coupling() {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<NUM_REGIONS;i++){
        out[i].write(0);
    }
    flag = 0;
    while(flag == 0){
        wait();
        if(reset.read() == 1){
            int i;
            for(i = 0 ; i < NUM_REGIONS; i++){
                out[i].write(0);
            }
            done.write(0);
        }
        else if(en.read() == 1){
            int i,j;
            done.write(0);
            for(i=0; i<NUM_REGIONS;i++){
                for(j=0; j<NUM_REGIONS;j++){
                    if(!(input_0[i][j] = fifo_input_0.read())) cout << "fifo0 is empty" << endl;
                    if(!(input_1[i][j] = fifo_input_1.read())) cout << "fifo1 is empty" << endl;
                }
            }

            for(i = 0 ; i < NUM_REGIONS; i++){
                sum = 0;
                for(j = 0; j < NUM_REGIONS; j++){
                    sum += input_0[i][j]*input_1[i][j];
                    wait();
                }
                out[i].write(a.read()*sum);
                wait();
            }
            done.write(1);
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}

SC_CTOR(method_coupling): fifo_input_0 ("fifo_input_0", NUM_REGIONS*NUM_REGIONS), fifo_input_1 ("fifo_input_1", NUM_REGIONS*NUM_REGIONS) {
    SC_THREAD(do_coupling){
        //for(int i= 0; i<NUM_REGIONS; i++){
        //  sensitive << out[i];
        //}
        sensitive << en << reset << done << clock.pos();
    }
    SC_THREAD(init_0){
        sensitive << valid_data0 << clock.pos();
    }
    SC_THREAD(init_1){
        sensitive << valid_data1 << clock.pos();
    }
}

};
```

I am reading in data to a fifo (specifically two 10x10 double arrays) and then I use an enable signal to begin a matrix multiplication operation. When the 10x10 arrays have been multiplied, I raise a done signal at the end.

I can fully see how the error suggests I have infinite while loops, thus I am now using the while(flag == 0) instead of a while true loop.

Comment: Are you sure the tool likes SC_THREAD I use an alternate tool and have to use SC_CTHREAD constructs for my clocked stuff like this.

Comment: When I switch to SC_CTHREAD my simulation fails. Do I have to alter the usage of the CTHREADS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to review your code first. I am not SystemC expert, but I think there's a lot things are not synthesizable. For example you can't use `SC_THREAD` in HLS for synthesis. If you expect to synthesize your code, you should be coding it in a "hardware" way.